# 3DXML Catia files not showing

Tags: xml, html, 3d, catia

I have installed the 3D XML viewer plugin on my pc and Firefox detected it and I have allowed it.

I have added the `.3dxml` extension as `"application/octet-stream"` type in the server configuration.

I load my file with this code;

```
<object type='application/x-3dxmlplugin' id='3DXMLPluginId'>
<param name='DocumentFile' value='/img/test.3dxml'>
</object>
```

Nothing is shown. If i put a bad file name in my code I am getting a warning from 3dxml plugin like what the file is bad or corrupted. But when the filename is good i get nothing at all, no warning, nothing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is an example done in my CATIA_Portable_Script_Center. The idea is to use the right classid

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML><head>
<title>3DXML embeded page</title>
<META content="text/html; charset=unicode" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.6001.18876"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV class=copy>You will see a 3DXML file opened from DS website only if you 
have installed the free 3DXML player from Dassault Systemes (link <A 
href="http://www.3ds.com/products/3dvia/3d-xml/1/">http://www.3ds.com/products/3dvia/3d-xml/1/</A>&nbsp;).</DIV>
<DIV class=copy>To see how to embed a 3DXML file&nbsp;in a web page just view 
this page source code.</DIV>
<DIV class=copy>© 2010 Dassault Systemes - All rights reserved.</DIV>
<OBJECT id=viewer border=1 
codeBase="http://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS/3DVIA/3DXML/3dxml/3DXMLPlayerOnlineInstaller.exe" 
classid=clsid:5ABD296B-F8A0-436C-B2F7-B19170C43D28 width=800 height=600>   <PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="21166"><PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="15875"><PARAM    NAME="DocumentFile" VALUE="http://a3.media.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS/3DVIA/3DXML/gallery/3dxml_models/press_rink_axe_fta.3dxml"><PARAM NAME="Data" VALUE="">    
</OBJECT>
<DIV></DIV>

</BODY>
</html>
```